# convert an excel generated with exceljs to pdf

Tags: javascript, excel, angular, pdf, exceljs

I would like to convert my generated excel with exceljs module (angular) to PDF.
Here's my code that i generate excel with.

```
workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data) => {
    // code I use to export it as an Excel File
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8'});
    const test = FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'test.xlsx');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran accross the same exact problem. You can use libreConvert (just install libreoffice). Here is the exact code:

```
      // require fs module to read excel file and store pdf
      const fs = require('fs');
      // require promisify from bluebird to be able to await conversion to pdf
      const { promisify } = require('bluebird');
      // require libre and promisify the function to convert
      const libre = require('libreoffice-convert');
      const libreConvert = promisify(libre.convert);

      // read created excel file (this should be in an async function)
      let data = await fs.promises.readFile(path_to_excel_file);
      // convert to pdf 
      let pdfFile = await libreConvert(data, '.pdf', undefined);
      // store new created pdf
      await fs.promises.writeFile(`${dirName}/${docName}.pdf`, pdfFile);
```